# How to acquire multiple locks in VS2012 without messing up indentation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, auto-indent

This looks like a silly question, but I'm not able to find a solution to this.

My problem is that C# doesn't allow for the acquisition of multiple locks in a single `lock` statement. This won't work:

```
lock (a, b, c, d)
{
    // ...
}
```

Instead, it seems to require an insane amount of indentation in order to do this:

```
lock (a)
    lock (b)
        lock (c)
            lock (d)
            {
                // ...
            }
```

Coupled with all other indentation levels that the code is already in (namespaces, class, method, conditionals, loops, ...), this gets insane. So instead, I want to use this formatting:

```
lock (a) lock (b) lock (c) lock (d)
{
    // ...
}
```

and preserve my sanity. But Visual Studio (I'm using 2012) won't hear of it. As soon as I enter any closing brace, the above is transformed to something silly, like:

```
lock (a) lock (b) lock (c) lock (d)
                  {
                      // ...
                  }
```

And there seems there's nothing I can do. Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Do you have Resharper or similar installed?

Comment: @DaveZych No, I don't use any third-party modules.

Comment: One would hope that you're not doing this frequently. Acquiring multiple locks is probably the easiest possibly way to get yourself into a deadlock situation.

Comment: Not an answer to your question.. hence a comment.. why would you use so many locks to begin with.. You either have really complex and rare scenario.. or this is a red flag.

Comment: you could turn off auto-formatting....

Comment: As an alternative, you could also go to Tools / Options / Text Editor / C# / Tabs and reduce the tab and indent sizes, say to 2 spaces rather than 4. You'd still be indented but not as severely. I get that around the 8th or 10th or 12th level of indentation the code gets hard to read, but personally I think it's even harder to read when it's *not* indented.

Comment: @VikasGupta This is part of some diagnostics code (for debugging). That code needs all of the affected critical sections to not be running. So it's not a problem for normal operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using that many locks at a time is just asking for deadlock. Heck, even acquiring two different locks at a time runs that risk.

At the very least, you should be *very* very careful to only ever take these locks in exactly the same order everywhere that more than one is acquired at a time.

Also, "nice formatting" is in the eye of the beholder. That is, everyone's got their own idea of what's best. But, the following should work, without VS messing with it unless you specifically ask it to (e.g. by triggering an auto-format rule or explicitly auto-formatting):

```
lock (a)
lock (b)
lock (c)
lock (d)
{
}
```

You can also use this approach with `using` statements (where it's much more common to have more than one in a row), where the VS IDE already anticipates it.

Comment: Almost works, but not quite: the last lock gets automatically indented.

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea :- )

```
static class LockAndExecute
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    static void _gen(Action a, object[] objs, int i = 0){

        bool lockWasTaken = false;
        var temp = objs[i];
        try { 
            Monitor.Enter(temp, ref lockWasTaken); 
            if(i + 1 >= objs.Length) 
                a();
            else
                _gen(a, objs, i + 1);
        }
        finally 
        { 
            if (lockWasTaken) 
                Monitor.Exit(temp); 
        }
    }

    public static void Do(object[] objectsToLock, Action action){
            _gen(action, objectsToLock);
    }
}
```

and the usage;

```
LockAndExecute.Do(new[]{a, b}, () => {
    Console.WriteLine("Eww!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could work around the IDE's annoying behavior by changing your code, though the idea of changing your code to work around IDE behavior pains my conscience a little. I'd do it if it was a toy project but not on anything serious that another developer might work on.

Implement the lock with an `IDisposable` implementation. The `using` statement does not have the annoying indentation issue that the `lock` statements do.

```
class myLock : IDisposable
{
    private object _obj;

    public myLock(object obj)
    {
        _obj = obj;
        System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(obj);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(_obj);
        _obj = null;
    }

    public static void example()
    {
        var obj1 = new object();
        var obj2 = new object();
        var obj3 = new object();

        lock (obj1)
            lock (obj2)
                lock (obj3)
                {
                    // Stupid indentation >:(
                }

        using (new myLock(obj1))
        using (new myLock(obj2))
        using (new myLock(obj3))
        {
            // Ahhhh... :-)
        }
    }
}
```